# The range of $\arccos$

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is whether or not the function $\arccos$ takes complex numbers to complex numbers? Specifically, if we identify $\mathbb{R}$ with the subset of the complex numbers which have zero imaginary part, then is it true that $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ implies that $\arccos(z) \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$?

I know that $\arccos$ can be written as

$$ \arccos(z) = -i\log(z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1})$$

where one has to then fix a branch of $\log$ to work with, but I just haven't been able to show anything with this approach, which sort of makes me believe that it might not be true. Any insight (or potentially a counter-example) would be much appreciated!

Comment: You also need a branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$, of course.

Comment: $\arccos z$ is real if and only if $\log(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})$ is imaginary, which is true if and only if $\left|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|=1$. Not sure if that helps

Comment: You can also try $\arccos(z) = \frac{\pi}{2} + i\log(iz + \sqrt{1-z^2})$. This makes it easier for $z\in[-1,1]$ (you don't need a branch for $\sqrt{\cdot}$).

Comment: Why not $\arccos(z)=-i\log(z+i\sqrt{1-z^2})$? @Winther Seems more natural.

Comment: $\overline{\arccos(z)} = \arccos(\bar{z})$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's much easier if you use the property $\cos (\arccos z) = z$ of $\arccos$. The contrapositive of

$$z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}\implies \arccos z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$$

is

$$\arccos z\in \mathbb{R} \implies z \in \mathbb{R},$$

and we can immediately see that that is true since $\cos(\mathbb{R}) \subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is gorgeous, really.